# Making Reports with Report builder 3.0 OR SQL Server BI Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence

I have some questions about building reports in Report builder 3.0 OR SQL Server BI Studio 2008.

I use the report builder for the good wizard. Make better reports dan de BI wizard. And after that i work further in the BI Studio.

Now i have a problem i have a report(letter) that i need to generate. But i exists of 2 pages. The first page is a letter with the second page as Attachment with some calculations. So i may not printed on the same page. But i can't make 2 page's in de report builder or BI studio. How can i do that? Because i must place on each page a footer with some general info.

I use also data driven subscriptions for my reports. No problem with that. But i make the subscriptions on my pc. And they need to made on the customers pc. Can i export them on my pc to place them on theirs pc?

Is there also an option to call the data driven subscriptions from code ( vb.net )?
So that they get executed with all the data from that subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the rectangle en hide expression i have made the report.
So each subreport i placed in an rectangle with an page break before. So if one page doesn't exists. He doensn't generate a white page. A just added a page footer to that one report.

And he use that footer on each page.